# Как заменить число с плавающей запятой на число с плавающей точкой

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть текстовый файл с большим количеством строк такого формата -

**01.07.2020||zejrmoGlut||АдыааШтпфы||97856940||4,22324808||**

Я хочу записать этот файл в MS SQL, но я не могу записать число с плавающей **запятой**, но мне нельзя изменять в файле запятую на точку.

Как можно записать число с плавающей запятой в тип данных float БД. Ибо принимает только если вместо запятой точка.

```
Create Table Test
(
    RandomDate Date NOT NULL,
    EngSymbols varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    RusSymbols nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    RandomNum int NOT NULL,
    RandomDoubleNum float NOT NULL
);

BULK INSERT Test
From '1.txt'
With (
    Check_Constraints,
    FieldTerminator = '||',
    RowTerminator = '||\n', 
    CodePage = '65001'
    );
```

**Использую MS SQL 2019. Предпочтительно через запрос как это сделать.**

Comment: Скопируйте файл, отредактируйте копию, импортируйте.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А без редактирования никак?

Comment: Без редактирования никак.

Comment: SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) could help

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thanks, but I want to import the data via T-SQL.

Comment: Залейте в промежуточную таблицу в виде текста, поменяйте в колонке ',' на '.' и перелейте в итоговую

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Спасибо, помогли!